# Мини игра в консоли отладки

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Суть игры: передвигаться, нажимая стрелочки на клавиатуре, обходя стены.
Проблема игры: карта каким - то образом переворачивается, но не визуализирует этот (ошибочный) переворот

```
Console.CursorVisible = false;
char[,] map =
{
    { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',},
    { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#',}

};

int userX = 6, userY = 6;

while (true)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(map[i, j]);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(userX, userY);
    Console.Write('@');
    ConsoleKeyInfo charKey = Console.ReadKey();
    switch (charKey.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
            if (map[userX, userY - 1] != '#')
            {
                userY--;
            }
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
            if (map[userX, userY + 1] != '#')
            {
                userY++;
            }
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
            if (map[userX - 1, userY] != '#')
            {
                userX--; 
            }
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
            if (map[userX + 1, userY] != '#')
            {
                userX++;
            }
            break;
    }
    Console.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не `map[x, y]`, а `map[y, x]`, вы индексы перепутали, сначала идёт строка, а потом колонка.

```
switch (charKey.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
        if (map[userY - 1, userX] != '#')
        {
            userY--;
        }
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
        if (map[userY + 1, userX] != '#')
        {
            userY++;
        }
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
        if (map[userY, userX - 1] != '#')
        {
            userX--; 
        }
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
        if (map[userY, userX + 1] != '#')
        {
            userX++;
        }
        break;
}
```

Чтобы не путаться, пишите не `x` и `y`, а например `row` и `col`.

Comment: Большое спасибо!